# i am making an camera app ,i need white frame when camera open like lenkart is there any way to do it in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

i want to place a frame when camera open as you can see in lenskart App.i searched for for it but didn't find it ,is there any way to do it ?

i am making an camera app where a frame with white borders is needed to added when camera starts and the customer needs to place his face under that box to capture the image.is there any way to do this ??i tried this [Planning a cordova camera plugin with transparent overlay image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33762526/planning-a-cordova-camera-plugin-with-transparent-overlay-image)
but this is not working.